# Pasing Json String to Objects

Tags: java, json

I've been stuck on the same problem for two weeks, so any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to parse an API's response, but I keep getting errors whatever I try. I would like to be able to parse the String and extract each filing to objects so that I can use them later in a GUI and categorize them.

Here is a sample of the response:

```
{
    "filings": [
        {
            "id": "fil_ol1QrN",
            "filing_date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 10,
                "day": 9
            },
            "accepted_date": {
                "dateTime": {
                    "date": {
                        "year": 2019,
                        "month": 10,
                        "day": 9
                    },
                    "time": {
                        "hour": 18,
                        "minute": 32,
                        "second": 27,
                        "nano": 0
                    }
                },
                "offset": {
                    "totalSeconds": 0
                }
            },
            "period_end_date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 10,
                "day": 7
            },
            "report_type": "4",
            "sec_unique_id": "0000320193-19-000109",
            "filing_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000109/0000320193-19-000109-index.htm",
            "report_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000109/xslF345X03/wf-form4_157066032478147.xml"
        },
        {
            "id": "fil_6GoeOv",
            "filing_date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 10,
                "day": 3
            },
            "accepted_date": {
                "dateTime": {
                    "date": {
                        "year": 2019,
                        "month": 10,
                        "day": 3
                    },
                    "time": {
                        "hour": 18,
                        "minute": 31,
                        "second": 27,
                        "nano": 0
                    }
                },
                "offset": {
                    "totalSeconds": 0
                }
            },
            "period_end_date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 10,
                "day": 1
            },
            "report_type": "4",
            "sec_unique_id": "0000320193-19-000106",
            "filing_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000106/0000320193-19-000106-index.htm",
            "report_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000106/xslF345X03/wf-form4_157014186524822.xml"
        },
        {
            "id": "fil_Vb3JD0",
            "filing_date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 10,
                "day": 3
            },
            "accepted_date": {
                "dateTime": {
                    "date": {
                        "year": 2019,
                        "month": 10,
                        "day": 3
                    },
                    "time": {
                        "hour": 18,
                        "minute": 33,
                        "second": 22,
                        "nano": 0
                    }
                },
                "offset": {
                    "totalSeconds": 0
                }
            },
            "period_end_date": {
                "year": 2019,
                "month": 10,
                "day": 1
            },
            "report_type": "4",
            "sec_unique_id": "0000320193-19-000107",
            "filing_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000107/0000320193-19-000107-index.htm",
            "report_url": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000107/xslF345X03/wf-form4_157014197957378.xml"
        }
    ],
    "company": {
        "id": "com_NX6GzO",
        "ticker": "AAPL",
        "name": "Apple Inc",
        "lei": "HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394",
        "cik": "0000320193"
    },
    "next_page": "MjAxOS0xMC0wM3w1NzcwMTQ0"
}
```

In this, I'm pulling 3 different filings and I tried extracting the ids and report types of each to start with the following code that I took in another similar SO question:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ExtractSECFilings {

    private Map<String, MyObject> filings = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();

    public Map<String, MyObject> getfilings() {
        return filings;
    }

    public void setFilings(Map<String, MyObject> filings) {
        this.filings = filings;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "filings{" +
                "filings=" + filings +
                '}';
    }
}

class MyObject {
    private String id;
    private String report_type;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getReportType() {
        return report_type;
    }

    public void setReportType(String report_type) {
        this.report_type = report_type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", report_type='" + report_type + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


}
```

Now in the main method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.intrinio.api.*;
import com.intrinio.models.*;

import com.intrinio.invoker.*;
import com.intrinio.invoker.auth.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Proxy.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import org.threeten.bp.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException {

        ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
        ApiKeyAuth auth = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("ApiKeyAuth");
        auth.setApiKey("INSERT_API_KEY");

        CompanyApi companyApi = new CompanyApi();

        String identifier = "AAPL";
        String reportType = null;
        LocalDate startDate = null; 
        LocalDate endDate = null; 
        Integer pageSize = 3; 
        String nextPage = null;

        try {
            ApiResponseCompanyFilings result = companyApi.getCompanyFilings(identifier, reportType, startDate, endDate,
                    pageSize, nextPage);

            String convertedResult = new Gson().toJson(result);
            System.out.println(convertedResult);

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ExtractSECFilings readValue = mapper.readValue(convertedResult, ExtractSECFilings.class);
            System.out.println("readValue = " + readValue);

        } catch (ApiException | IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception when calling CompanyApi#getCompanyFilings");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I got the following error:

> Exception when calling CompanyApi#getCompanyFilings
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY
>   token  at [Source:
>   (String)"{"filings":[{"id":"fil_ol1QrN","filing_date":{"year":2019,"month":10,"day":9},"accepted_date":{"dateTime":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":10,"day":9},"time":{"hour":18,"minute":32,"second":27,"nano":0}},"offset":{"totalSeconds":0}},"period_end_date":{"year":2019,"month":10,"day":7},"report_type":"4","sec_unique_id":"0000320193-19-000109","filing_url":"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000109/0000320193-19-000109-index.htm","report_url":"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/da"[truncated
>   1342 chars]; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain:
>   jsonToObjects.ExtractSECFilings["filings"])

I've tried following many tutorials and keep getting errors. I'm new to programming, so again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You convert `ApiResponseCompanyFilings` to JSON using Gson and that JSON to `ExtractSECFilings` using Jackson. Since you don't do anything with the JSON, why don't you convert `ApiResponseCompanyFilings` directly to `ExtractSECFilings`? Also, I don't see why you use `Map` here when `fillings` is an array. The exception is telling you the same, btw.

Comment: go to this site:  https://app.quicktype.io/  it will convert example json to java or other language.

Comment: Thank you OldProgrammer, that's a very handy site, but I prefer coding the entire thing by hand to learn. I appreciate the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess from the above json you are trying to get the json nodes "id" and "report_type"

````
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
class Wrapper{


  @JsonProperty(value="filings")
  List<ExtractSECFilings> filings;

  public List<ExtractSECFilings> getFillings() {
    return filings;
  }

  public void setFillings(List<ExtractSECFilings> fillings) {
    this.filings = fillings;
  } 
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
 class ExtractSECFilings {

 String id;
 String report_type;

public String getId() {
  return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
  this.id = id;
}
public String getReport_type() {
  return report_type;
}
public void setReport_type(String report_type) {
  this.report_type = report_type;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "ExtractSECFilings [id=" + id + ", report_type=" + report_type + "]";
}
}

//here add this code in  your main application to serialize the json

public class Demo{
public static void main(String args[]){
 Wrapper wrapper=mapper.readValue(val, Wrapper.class);
    System.out.println(wrapper.getFillings());
}
}
```
in the console you can see that id and report type json node values
````

Comment: What if I wanted the urls and the filed dates? I can't figure that one out either

Answer (score 0):

It can not match your pojo property with you json string. Try to change `private Map<String, MyObject> filings = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();` to `private List<MyObject> filings = new ArrayList<>();`

**UPD:** If it occurs `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException`, just add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation on `ExtractSECFilings` class.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
static class ExtractSECFilings {}
```